# Concatenar Archivos .TXT

Tags: windows

Tengo 2 archivos .txt y necesito concatenar las filas, me explico:

Archivo: 1.txt

codigo1= (esta en la fila 1 del .txt)
codigo2= (esta en la fila 2 del .txt)
codigo3= (esta en la fila 3 del .txt)

Archivo: 2.txt

111 (esta en la fila 1 del .txt)
222 (esta en la fila 2 del .txt)
333 (esta en la fila 3 del .txt)

El resultado deberia quedar asi:

Archivo 3.txt

codigo1=111
codigo2=222
codigo3=333

Observación: Esto es solo un ejemplo muy basico, ya que imagen que son archivos con aprox. 2000 lineas o mas donde son frases ( no solo numeros).

Estaba tratando de utilizar el notepad++ , pero demoro mucho en realizar este proceso.

Comment: Hola , bienvenido . cuéntenos que avance tiene del problema , en que lenguaje desea realizar dicha tarea? podemos ayudarle en problemas específicos de su código más no una tare completa.

Comment: Dev.Joel .... la verdade que he programado nada.
Pienso utilizar una herramienta (  excel, notepad++) , pero si se puede hacer en Java  agradeceria mucho su ayuda.....

Answer (score -1):

Si usas Linux es el siguiente comando en la consola

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > new.txt
```

en windows en la consola aplica lo siguiente:

```
copy /b file1+file2+file3 targetfile
```

saludos.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, voy a probar si sirve.
Hay solo un problema .....
Yo necesito que la fila1 del archivo1 se concatene con la fila1 del archivo2 , eso debe ocurrir con las demas filas hasta la fila numero 2000.

Comment: hice prueba con comando cat en Linux y lo que hace es copiar el contenido abajo del contenido del primer archivo.

Lo que necesito es concatenar filas
archivo1(fila1) = archivo2 (fila1)
archivo1(fila2) = archivo2(fila2)
archivo1(fila3) = archivo2(fila3)
.

Comment: Hola como la pregunta decía concatenar dos archivos , ahora con la explicación que me diste encontré una solución en el siguiente enlace:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113898/how-to-merge-two-files-based-on-the-matching-of-two-columns

saludos.